# In Visual Studio when viewing a changeset, how can I change the view of cs files?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, tfs

In Visual Studio with TFS as source control, when I view the history and double click a cs file, the file is loaded in notepad. How can i change the application to be notepad++?

I also would like the OS's default application for the file to still be visual studio

Answer (score 20):

After pouring over [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) logs I think I found the solution!

You need to change the what the Windows shell (explorer) thinks the "Edit" action for text files. I was able to change this key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\text\shell\edit\command`

to something other than Notepad (in my case notepad2). Now Visual Studio's TFS's changeset dialog opens cs files with that editor.

This will probably change the edit option for not just cs files, but everything considered "text'. The registry entries for file associations are pretty complicated. I suspect that it would be possible to disassociate .cs files from this common "text" category and make this change only for cs files (but I'm not that ambitious). Also, I wouldn't be surprised if people's file associations / shell commands (open, edit, etc...) vary from machine to machine (OS versions, tools installed, etc) - so YMMV.

Comment: Your solutions works for me, even for source code files (tested .CPP and .H files). I used Notepad++. This is not exactly the solution I was hoping for, but it definitely better than viewing code in Notepad. I wonder why MS don't let us open file history in Visual Studio directly.

Comment: awesome. syntax editing when viewing changeset files. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Notepad++ should really have this option in the installer so we don't have to keep using Open With.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found is to replace notepad with notepad++.  This [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12617/how-to-replace-notepad-in-windows-7/) describes how to do it.  Don't forget to check the comments to get a link to the "little exe" that comes with notepad++.
Works like a charm on W7 x64.

Cheers,
Phil

Answer (score 2):

\I was able to configure this by adding new value to the registry.

OS: Windows 7 Enterprise x64

Steps on how to do it.

1. Run: **Regedit** (alt + r, type regedit)
2. Look for  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations`
3. Right click "SystemFileAssociation" -> add new key then name it as **.cs**
4. Right click .cs and add new key then name it as **shell**
5. Right click **shell** and add new keys name it as **edit** and **open** 6
6. Right click **edit** and add new key **command** then change the default value to point to the file exe you want it to run.
   ex: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe %1**

    
   Don't forget to add the %1 at the end of the .exe
7. do the same for **open**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any options in Visual Studio for changing that, so I'm guessing it uses the system's default text editor.

Try assigning Notepad++ as the default handler for *.cs files.

You can do this from withing Notepad++ by going to Settings/Preference/File Association.

You can also do it by right-clicking on a .cs file in explorer, go to Open With/Choose Program..., then select Notepad++ and check the "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" box before hitting OK.

Comment: I can change the default application to notepad++ (the changeset viewer even shows the n++ logo for .cs files), but .cs files still open in notepad. Any other ideas?

Comment: Don't know of anything else to do.  I've run into similar problems.  Double-clicking on .java files causes Word (of all things) to open.  Which is extra strange.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that works for me is when I set the default program for the particular file type in Windows Explorer to open with the VS IDE:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

This opens the code in a new instance of VS. Not ideal, but at least it's easier to read.